# How to run a function after another function is done in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just learned python the other day, I was wondering how I can make the function **vc_s2()** wait for function **vc_s1()** to be done before running, and the same for **vc_s3()** with **vc_s2()**?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
from funtions import vc_s1, vc_s2, vc_s3

vc_s1()

vc_s2()

vc_s3()
```

Comment: you have already done it

Comment: If this code does not do what you want, then please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `vc_s1()` must return before `vc_s2` can be called. However, that doesn't mean `vc_s1` isn't starting a new thread or process that does *not* need to complete before `vc_s1` returns.

Comment: Most Straightforward Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python runs chronologically, so it goes from top to bottom, as long as you have the 3 functions in order you should be fine.